# Learning roadmap for p-adic modular forms and eigenvarieties.

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

What are some good sources for breaking into the field of p-adic modular forms?  It was suggested to me to read Katz' paper "P-adic Properties of Modular Schemes and Modular Forms".  I have found this paper to be helpful, albeit difficult.  Where does one go from here?

Comment: Emerton's note "P-adic geometry of modular curves" is a useful gentle intro. There are some wonderful lecture notes by Kevin Buzzard from the Harvard eigenvarieties semester in 2005, but these were never published; if you ask around at your department you might find someone who has a copy.

Comment: David, are you referring to these notes on Buzzard's website?  http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/maths/research/papers/eigenvarieties.pdf

Comment: No, your link is to a preprint version of Buzzard's article in the 2007 Durham proceedings. If you're going to read that I'd suggest first reading the 2004 article "On p-adic families..." (Progr. Math. 224).